# gremlin python retrieve ids and labels (valueMap(True))

Tags: python, python-3.x, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

`python g.V('test_red1').valueMap().toList()`

works fine but when I pass true to request ids and labels I get this error. Anything I am missing?

```
g.V('test_red1').valueMap(True).toList()

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/merchantGraph/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 52, in toList
    return list(iter(self))
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/merchantGraph/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 43, in __next__
 ...
```

Am I missing something. I am using AWS Neptune ...

I am adding extra import statements

and traceback

```
import time
import requests
import json
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection


import boto3
from os import environ

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(environ['gremlinNeptuneConnection'],'g'))


# this works
g.V('test_red1').valueMap().toList()

# this fails
g.V('test_red1').valueMap(True).toList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/merchantGraph/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 52, in toList
    return list(iter(self))
  ....
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/merchantGraph/gremlin_python/structure/io/graphsonV3d0.py", line 455, in objectify
    new_dict[reader.toObject(l[x])] = reader.toObject(l[x + 1])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: You are missing something indeed - a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is g? What do you expect to happen? Where's the rest of the traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are running into trouble with this recently reported bug with `valueMap(true)`:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1860

it is patched and will be fixed with release of 3.3.2. Until then you will have to work around the issue as there really is no fix short of reverting to GraphSON 2.0 (which comes with it's own set of downsides). One workaround would be to `project()` your results:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('props','id','label').
......1>         by(valueMap()).
......2>         by(id).
......3>         by(label)
==>[props:[name:[marko],age:[29]],id:1,label:person]
==>[props:[name:[vadas],age:[27]],id:2,label:person]
==>[props:[name:[lop],lang:[java]],id:3,label:software]
==>[props:[name:[josh],age:[32]],id:4,label:person]
==>[props:[name:[ripple],lang:[java]],id:5,label:software]
==>[props:[name:[peter],age:[35]],id:6,label:person]
```